# Multiple datasets in gnuplot: difference in behavior of index with iteration vs range

Tags: dataset, indexing, gnuplot

I think I understand from the behavior **how** these two plot commands differ, but I don't really understand **why** they differ.  That is, I didn't expect there to be a difference.  The two cases are:

```
plot for [i=0:3] 'ctg-y2.dat' index i using 2 title columnheader(2) with lines
```

and

```
plot 'ctg-y2.dat' index 0:3 using 2 title columnheader(2) with lines
```

(the example datafile is http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/demo/ctg-y2.dat)

The first one does what I would expect: for each of four datasets in the file, read a column header from the first line of the dataset, and plot the remaining data.  The second one does something rather different: it does *not* read a column header for any dataset but the first, and it seems to plot all the data as if it were part of one dataset.  The result is a mess, since the implicit x values don't match up correctly.

The description of index in the manual doesn't talk about this behavior of using a range with index, as near as I can tell.  Is it documented somewhere?  Is this a bug?  Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the `index` before, but if I understand it correctly, it seems to merge all indexed data sets to a single set. This is why the lines all appear in the red color. However, if plotted against the column index and not a given index (e.g. `using 2` vs `using 1:2`) it seems to fall back to index 1. This is due to the fact that the first line cannot be interpreted (since it is a title).
The issue with the column headers seems to be working ok, since gnuplot expects to have just a single dataset, which is combined with the keyword `index`, and therefor does not expect to have multiple column headers.

Since you already solved your problem with the iterations there is no need for further suggestions. I think this is exactly how you should plot your data.

Comment: The thing that doesn't make sense is that gnuplot is clearly treating the input as if it contains multiple datasets even when I use the range syntax.  If I plot using the dataset pseudocolumn -2 for x (`plot 'ctg-y2.dat' index 0:3 using -2:2 title columnheader(2)`) I get four different columns, one for each dataset.  So they're not just being merged together into a single dataset.